# Repeated linear-gradient on page

Tags: css, gradient

I have a page with a diagonal made with CSS, using linear-gradient.

```
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-63.5deg,  #999cdb 50%, #f6bdbd 50%);
```

That will make a diagonal line from the right-upper corner till left-lower corner. The problem is that, when the user clicks my sign-in/sign-up form the model changes its height. And so, the diagonal does not re-calculate its positioning. The linear gradient repeats itself and that's just ugly.

Does anyone have any idea how to make it recalculate its positioning? I've tried a lot and didn't succeed. Thanks.

Here is the HTML code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sweety &amp; Co. Pro</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!--<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>-->
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,300,600,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/style_pages.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/sign-in-up.css">

    <style>

        #body {
            display: block;
            padding: 1%;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>


<div id="con">

    <div id="header">
        <a href="#"><img src="../static/img/logo.svg" width="314" height="81">  </a>
    </div>


    <div id="body">

        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="">
                <ul class="tab-group">
                    <!--<li style="z-index: 7;"><span class="underline"><a href="#"><span>link</span></a> </span> </li>-->
                    <li class="tab active"><a id="asignin" href="#login"><span>SIGN IN</span></a></li>
                    <li class="tab"><a id="asignup" href="#signup"><span>SIGN UP</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="login">
                    <form>
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="inputfield">
                                <input type="email" id="email-login" required>
                                <label for="email-login">Email</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="inputfield">
                                <input type="password" id="password-login" required>
                                <label for="password-login">Password</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="inputfield ">
                                <input class='toggle' type="checkbox" name='check-4'>
                                <p style="display: inline; margin-left: 5px" > <b>Keep me Signed in</b></p>

                            </div>

                            <div class="inputfield">
                            <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">SIGN IN</button>-->
                            <!--<a role="button" type="submit">SIGN IN</a>-->
                                <input type="submit" value="SIGN IN">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div id="signup">
                    <div class="splash">
                        <h2>Get your time and money on track</h2>
                        <h1>$9.90 </h1><h2>/month</h2>
                    </div>

                    <form>
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="inputfield halfwidth">
                                <input type="text" id="firstname" required>
                                <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="inputfield halfwidth">
                                <input type="text" id="lastname" required>
                                <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="inputfield">
                                <input type="email" id="email" required>
                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="inputfield halfwidth">
                                <input type="password" id="password" required>
                                <label for="Password">Password</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="inputfield halfwidth">
                                <input type="password" id="re-password" required>
                                <label for="Re-Password">Re-Password</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="inputfield halfwidth">
                                <div class="select-wrapper select--white">
                                    <select name="demo">
                                        <option value="freelancer" selected>freelancer</option>
                                        <option value="small">small company (1-10)</option>
                                        <option value="medium">medium company (11-50)</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="inputfield halfwidth">
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input class='toggle' type="checkbox" name='check-4'>
                                </div>

                                <div id="terms"> <p>Accept <a href="#terms">terms</a> and conditions.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                    <div id="basebtpay">
                        <div id="btpay"><img src="../static/img/paypal.png"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <img src="../static/img/sco.svg" width="129" height="79">
    </div>
</div>

<script src="../static/js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
html{
    height:  100%;
}

body {
    /*height: 100%;*/
    font-size: 62.5%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
    -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
    -o-text-size-adjust: none;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;

}

body {

}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { /*reset for mobile browsers */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
}

body {
    position: relative;
    background: #B3DCEC;
    /*background: -moz-linear-gradient(-63.5deg, #999cdb 50%, #f6bdbd 50%);*/
    /*background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(50%, #999cdb), color-stop(50%, #f6bdbd), );*/
    /*background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-63.5deg,  #999cdb 50%, #f6bdbd 50%);*/
    /*background: -o-linear-gradient(-63.5deg,  #999cdb 50%, #f6bdbd 50%);*/
    /*background: -ms-linear-gradient(-63.5deg,  #999cdb 50%, #f6bdbd 50%);*/
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #999cdb 50%, #f6bdbd 50%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top left, #999cdb 50%, #f6bdbd 50%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top left, #999cdb 50%, #f6bdbd 50%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #999cdb 50%, #f6bdbd 50%);
    /*background: linear-gradient(-63.5deg, #999cdb 50%, #f6bdbd 50%);*/
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#999cdb', endColorstr='#f6bdbd', GradientType=1);

    font-family: 'Montserrat';

    font-size: 1.4rem;  /* =14px */
}


#container {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}

#header {

    padding:20px;
}

#body {
    display: block;
    padding: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    padding-bottom: 150px;
}

#footer {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background: none;
    color: #003;
    margin-top: 30px;
    height: 100px;
}

#footer img {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}

p {font-family: 'Montserrat';  font-size: 1.4rem;
    color:#fff;}

a { color:#9A9ADD;
    text-decoration:underline;}

.clear {clear:both;}

.inspiration {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-bottom: 32px;
    text-align: center;
}

.inspiration a {color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);}

.inspiration a:hover {color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);}

.inspiration a:active {color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);}

.splash-left h1 {
    letter-spacing: -1rem;
    font-family: 'montserrat';
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 9rem;
    font-size: 11.4rem;
}

.splash-left {
    margin: 5%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 0%;
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
}

.splash {
    padding: 50px;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
}

.wrapper {
    background: #282731;
    border-radius: 1px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 22px 17px 58px 3px rgba(89,51,51,0.59);
    -moz-box-shadow: 22px 17px 58px 3px rgba(89,51,51,0.59);
    box-shadow: 22px 17px 58px 3px rgba(89,51,51,0.59);
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 600px;
    width: 100%;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 12.4rem;
    line-height: 100%;
    margin: initial;
    letter-spacing: -1rem;
    font-weight: 800;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 3.0rem;
    line-height: 100%;
    letter-spacing: -0.2rem;
    margin: initial;
}

h3 {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 400;


}

.textform {
    border: solid 0px;
    width: 245px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px; }


form {}

.button {
    background: #999CDB;
    border: none;
    color: #fafafa;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
    border-radius: 40px;
    margin-top: 5%;
    padding: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: initial;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.button:hover {
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    color: rgb(40, 39, 49);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
    border-radius: 40px;
    margin-top: 5%;
    padding: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: initial;
    text-decoration:none;

}



#btpay {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #FFC520;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 250px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#basebtpay {
    background-color:#353442;
    padding:20px;}


.button:focus {
    border: none;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    outline: none;
}

.button:hover {
    border: none;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}

.button:active {color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);}

.container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 0;
    padding: 16px 48px 32px;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.photo {
    background-image: url(https://pmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/margot-robbie-good-photo.jpg?w=340&h=299&crop=1);
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 120px;
    border: solid #FFF 8px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: -85px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 120px;
}

.inputfield {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.inputfield.halfwidth {width: 50%;}

input {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #F6BDBD;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #F6BDBD;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 2;
    background-color: #282731;
    margin: 24px 0;
    padding-right: 8px;
    width: 100%;
}

input:focus {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #F6BDBD;
    outline: none;
}

label {
    color: #F6BDBD;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: 32px;
    transition: ease all .4s;
}

input:valid + label {
    color: #9E9E9E;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    top: 8px;
}

input:focus + label,
input:active + label {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    top: 8px;
}

#terms {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 67px;
    margin-top: -24px; }

#terms p {
    font-size:12px; }




/*FANCY CHECKER*/

div.controls {
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
div.controls h1 {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: -10px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    color: #fafafa;
    background-color: #54bded;
}

input[type='radio'],
input[type='checkbox'] {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type='radio']:focus, input[type='radio']:active,
input[type='checkbox']:focus,
input[type='checkbox']:active {
    outline: none;
}
input[type='radio'] + label,
input[type='checkbox'] + label {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: #0b4c6a;
}
input[type='radio'] + label:before, input[type='radio'] + label:after,
input[type='checkbox'] + label:before,
input[type='checkbox'] + label:after {
    content: '';
    font-family: helvetica;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
}
input[type='radio'] + label:before,
input[type='checkbox'] + label:before {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
input[type='radio'] + label:after,
input[type='checkbox'] + label:after {
    color: #fff;
}
input[type='radio']:checked + label:before,
input[type='checkbox']:checked + label:before {
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 10px #158EC6;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 10px #158EC6;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 10px #158EC6;
}

/*Radio Specific styles*/
input[type='radio'] + label:before {
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
input[type='radio'] + label:hover:after, input[type='radio']:checked + label:after {
    content: '\2022';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 15px;
}
input[type='radio'] + label:hover:after {
    color: #c7c7c7;
}
input[type='radio']:checked + label:after, input[type='radio']:checked + label:hover:after {
    color: #fff;
}

/*Checkbox Specific styles*/
input[type='checkbox'] + label:before {
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
input[type='checkbox'] + label:hover:after, input[type='checkbox']:checked + label:after {
    content: "\2713";
    line-height: 18px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
input[type='checkbox'] + label:hover:after {
    color: #c7c7c7;
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked + label:after, input[type='checkbox']:checked + label:hover:after {
    color: #fff;
}

/*Toggle Specific styles*/
input[type='checkbox'].toggle {
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    margin: 0px;
    appearance: none;
    width: 55px;
    height: 28px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    position: relative;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
@inlcude box-shadow(none);
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
input[type='checkbox'].toggle:hover:after {
    background-color: #c7c7c7;
}
input[type='checkbox'].toggle:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: #aeaeae;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked.toggle {
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 15px #158EC6;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 15px #F6BDBD;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 15px #F6BDBD;
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked.toggle:after {
    left: 29px;
    background-color: #282731;
}

/*CUSTOM SELECT*/
*, *:after, *:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.position-center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
.position-center .select-wrapper {
    margin: 0 20px;
}

/*******************************
        Styles to copy
*******************************/
/*
* Basic resets for select element
*/

.select-wrapper select {
    width: auto;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    /*IOS*/
}

.select-wrapper select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
    /*IE10*/
}

/*
* Global styles
*/
.select-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.select-wrapper:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    background-position: left center;
}

.select-wrapper:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    line-height: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;
}

/*******************************
          White theme
*******************************/
.select--white {
    /*
     * Customize options
     */
    /*
     * Hover styles
     */
    /*
     * Select element
     */
}
.select--white:after, .select--white select {

    color: black;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: 100ms all cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
    transition: 100ms all cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
}
.select--white:after {
    width: 35px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
    border-left: 0;
}
.select--white:before {
    color: black;
    right: 20px;
    font-size: 15px !important;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    content: '\2193';
}
.select--white:hover:after, .select--white:hover select {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
.select--white select {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-right: 75px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: black;
}


/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    /* Styles */
    .inputfield.halfwidth {width: 100% !important;}
    .wrapper {

        background: #282731;
        border-radius: 1px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 22px 17px 58px 3px rgba(89,51,51,0.59);
        -moz-box-shadow: 22px 17px 58px 3px rgba(89,51,51,0.59);
        box-shadow: 22px 17px 58px 3px rgba(89,51,51,0.59);
        margin-right:0px;
        position: relative;
        max-width: 450px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 321px) {


}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) and (max-width : 768px) {

    .box {
        width: 94% !important;
        min-width: 270px !important;
        border: solid 12px;
        border-color: white;
        margin-right: 2%;
        float: left;
        padding: 20px;
        min-height: 180px !important;
        margin-top: 4%;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 15px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #hello h1 {color:#222;
        font-size: 6rem !important;
        letter-spacing: -.5rem;
        line-height: 5rem;

    }

    .hello-boy {display:none !important; }
    .button {
        background: #999CDB;
        border: none;
        color: #fafafa;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 400;
        border-radius: 40px;
        margin:0px;
        margin-top: 5%;
        padding: 16px;
        display: inline-block;
        width: initial;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .button:hover {
        background: #fff;
        border: none;
        color: rgb(40, 39, 49);
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 400;
        border-radius: 40px;
        margin:0px;
        margin-top: 5%;
        padding: 16px;
        display: inline-block;
        width: initial;
        text-decoration:none;

    }



    #body {
        padding: 13%;
    }

    .splash-left {
        margin: 5%;
        display: inline-block;
        padding-bottom: 0%;
        position: relative;
        width: 90%;
    }

    .hello-boy {display:none;}

    .splash-left h1 {
        letter-spacing: -.5rem;
        font-family: 'montserrat';
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-left: 0px;
        color: #fff;
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 200px;
        font-size: 9rem;
        line-height: 7rem;
    }

    .inputfield.halfwidth {width: 100% !important;}

    .splash {
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #fff;
        padding-bottom: 5%;
        margin: 0px;
        position: relative;
        width: 300px;
    }

    .wrapper {

        background: #282731;
        border-radius: 1px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 22px 17px 58px 3px rgba(89,51,51,0.59);
        -moz-box-shadow: 22px 17px 58px 3px rgba(89,51,51,0.59);
        box-shadow: 22px 17px 58px 3px rgba(89,51,51,0.59);
        position: relative;
        max-width: 450px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    h1 {
        font-family:'Montserrat';
        font-size: 8.4rem;
        line-height: 100%;
        margin: initial;
    }

    h2 {
        font-family: 'Montserrat';
        font-size: 2rem;
        line-height: 100%;
        margin: initial;
        margin-top: 20px;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
    }

    /* Styles */
}



/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
    .inputfield.halfwidth {width: 100% !important;}
    .hello-boy {display:none !important; }


    /* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
    /* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
    .inputfield.halfwidth {width: 100% !important;}



    /* Styles */
}
/**********
iPad 3
**********/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
    /* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
    /* Styles */

}
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 1024px) {

    #menu {display:none;} }


@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 1600px) {

    .box {
        width: 30% !important;
        min-width: 160px;
        border: solid 12px;
        border-color: white;
        margin-right: 2%;
        float: left;
        padding: 20px;
        height: 180px !important;
        margin-top: 4%;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 15px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

}

Images:
```

[Page during sign-in active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vm7u.png)

[Page during sign-up active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25R4C.png)

Comment: Can you provide us with a demo to visualise the problem?

Comment: Code posted, folks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that if your width or height can change, fixed degree won't work out. You need it to be relative to size.

this can be used:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #999cdb 50%, #f6bdbd 50%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top left, #999cdb 50%, #f6bdbd 50%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top left, #999cdb 50%, #f6bdbd 50%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #999cdb 50%, #f6bdbd 50%);
```

Comment: That didn't work out. Same problem persists. Still struggling.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/21khur1d/ don't you want something like it? If you change width or height in the fiddle it's always at the desired corners.

Comment: The problem is, basically, when  the page loads, the sign-up option is active and the diagonal is perfectly traced. However, when I click the sign-up menu option, it does not recalculate. Your code didn't work either.

Comment: can you post images before and after user clicks sign-up menu option?

Comment: instead of body could you use `id="con"` div for background?

Comment: or try move `background-repeat: no-repeat;` style to same selector that contains `background: linear-gradient(...)` styles. Or try to add `top:0` and `background-size: cover;`

Comment: I tried everything you said. Acually with the .con option it worked but only for the .con div.

Comment: For the others, it worked but it lasts a piece of the page blank.

Comment: for body solution: I think setting height to 100% would work.

Comment: for .con solution: setting `position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%; top:0px; left:0px;` should make the div cover entire page.